# Style for template part in the WPF Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How we can set a style for a control which is a part of custom control in WPF ?

Comment: your question is not clear at all..add the valid code and description as what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is trying to set the `Template` property of the `CustomControl` itself and *not* that of the `TextBox` contained within the `CustomControl`. It's hard to answer a question like this when you haven't shown the XAML of the `TextBox` that you say you want to change the `ControlTemplate` of. As it is, I can only 'guide' you on how this might be done on any `TextBox`:

```
<Style TargetType="MyCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl}">
                <Grid>
                    ...
                    <TextBox Background="{Binding SomeBrushProperty}">
                        <TextBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <!--Define your TextBox ControlTemplate here-->
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </TextBox.Template>
                    </TextBox>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the future, please provide *all* of the relevant code in order to help you get answers quickly and accurately.

---

UPDATE>>>

Ok, after your question edit, I think I understand your question now. However, you cannot do this without either changing the code of your `CustomControl` or providing a new `ControlTemplate` for it (something like my first example).

If you *could* change the code, you would first need to create your `NewTextValue` `DependencyProperty` as the correct type that you want to use, eg. a `Brush`. Then you'd have to alter the XAML definition of the `CustomControl` to include this:

```
<TextBox Background="{Binding NewTextValue}">
```